# Discord JS : How to "iterate" a stringified JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, stringify

I'm learning JS (And discord JS to be accurate) since a few days. All goes well but now I'm before an issue I don't really know how to wrap my head around.

I have a sequelize database, all working well, aka an "User Card Collection", filling up as intended.
Now, I want to ask for a showing up of all "user_id" card collection.

I used a JSON.stringify (is it already the right way to do it ?). I can call it in console.log easily, showing up as a JSON. But how could I insert the list into an embed to PM it to the user ?

I've try to iterate it, it says me that it's, of course, not iterable.

Here is my concerned code :

```html
    } else if (command === 'Collection' || command === 'collec' || command === 'col') {     
                                            const target = message.author.id;                               
                                            const cards = await UserCollec.findAll({where: {user_id: target}, attributes: ['card_name', 'card_lvl', 'amount']});
                                            console.log(cards.every(card => card instanceof UserCollec)); // true if ok. DEBUG : working as intended.                                           
                                            const JSONcardlist = console.log(`${message.author}, all your cards :`, JSON.stringify(cards, null, 2)) // returns the JSON list. DEBUG : Working as intended.
```

When I try to call ${JSONcardlist} in a message or embed, it returns undefined. What am I missing ?

Thx for your help :) Probably something easy but, you know... Beginner here, not found the answer on internet in a few hours so better to ask.

Comment: Why are you iterating JSON and not actual arrays/objects?

Comment: Because I didn't know I had / how to do it.
I'll go take a look into this, thanks :)

Or to be more accurate, that's the only way I found to get the data I want from my sqilte db. I've tried a few other things which always came back undefined, that at least works in console, so I guessed it was a step closer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign Variables to JSON data in node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868732/assign-variables-to-json-data-in-node-js)

Comment: Could you please share a JSON snippet?

Comment: Maybe. I have the feeling that it's a little off what I want to do, but I'll learn with every example. I'll end up managing doing it when I'll understand how all of this works :)

Comment: This is the JSONcardcollection as it appear in console.log.

<@468720076095356928>, all your cards : [
  {
    "card_name": "Warrioress",
    "card_lvl": null,
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "card_name": "Lumberjack",
    "card_lvl": null,
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "card_name": "Shaman",
    "card_lvl": null,
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "card_name": "Witch",
    "card_lvl": null,
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "card_name": "Pilgrim",
    "card_lvl": null,
    "amount": 1
  }
]

That's what I want to embed in a message.

Comment: Oh, this copy/paste... I'll go host a screenshot online.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ch8NLfZ

This is what I want to "parse" and embed.

Answer (score 0):

That's ok, thx for help.

I found my solution with this :

```js
function GetCards(JSONcardlist) { return Object.values(cards).map(card => `• ${card.card_name} (lvl ${card.card_lvl}), ${card.amount} x`).join('\n')
                                        }
message.channel.send(GetCards(JSONcardlist))
```